# How to fix this closure syntax error: aka 'Optional<(Optional<UIActivityType>, Bool, Optional<Array<Any>>, Optional<Error>) -> ()>'

Tags: swift, closures, syntax-error

I am learning Ray Wenderlich.
I met a closure syntax error.
I want to know what do the Xcode tips mean?

The Xcode reports as following:

> /Users/.../FlickrPhotosViewController.swift:107:54: Cannot assign value of type '() -> ()' to type 'UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Bool, Optional>, Optional) -> ()>')

Here is the code:

```
let shareScreen = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageArray, applicationActivities: nil)
shareScreen.completionWithItemsHandler = { _ in
                self.sharing = false
}
```

Explanation is needed. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: answer = `shareScreen.completionWithItemsHandler = {
     (type,completed,items,error) in
      self.sharing = false
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expecting you to account for the four returned types, which is not clearly stated in the Ray Wenderlich course. Since these types are not used for the "share" action, you can replace the type names with _. This would also work:

```
shareScreen.completionWithItemsHandler = { (_, _, _, _) in
                self.sharing = false
            }
```